# Display Dropdown When Editing GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, drop-down-menu

I would like to display a field in my GridView as a DropDownList when a user is editing the row. The DropDownList would be pre-populated with two values, "Yes" and "No", and depending on which value a user selects I would like to set a variable.

Example:

I have a field called active. 1 = Active, 0 = Not Active. Although for the user I would like them to either set Active as "Yes" (1) or "No" (0). When when editing a row they could either choose "Yes" or "No" from the drop down and it would set a variable to either 1 or 0, so I can send that back in the SQL update.

I found this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

but it only tells me how to populate the DropDownList from a DataSource, which won't work for me since every field has either a yes or no for active. Also it displays a drop down even when just viewing the GridView, not just when editing.

I hope that makes sense, thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I have now, it almost works like I'd like it to. All I need to do now is change the label text to "Yes" if the value of Active is "True" and change the text to "No" if the value of Active is "False".

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Active")  %>'>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses. I just have one more question, see above.

Comment: I passed the Eval value to a method in the code behind to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the listitem like...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And you can bind the `SelectedValue` and it will automatically pass the DB a `1 or o`.

Comment: This would work if I just wanted the user to set the Active value, but I need to pull the current value for Active, and then in "edit" mode of the GridView change that value via drop down.

Comment: That's what the binding the SelectedValue property will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dropdown in `EditTemplate` and use a Label to show selection in `ItemTemplate`
See this example in  [msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) (scroll all the way to the end for dropdownlist scenario).

Answer (score 0):

1. put a label control (to show a current value in the database) and dropdownlist in edititem template

   ```
   <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("authostatus") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="Autharisationddl" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
   ```
2. In gridview rowdatabound event set the dropdown value according to label control value.

   ```
   if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
   {
     Label lbl= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl");
     DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl");

     if (lbl!= null)
     {
       if (lbl.Text == "1")
         ddl.SelectedValue = "1";
       else if (lbl.Text == "0")
         ddl.SelectedValue = "0";
     }
   }
   ```

thanks

Comment: This is helpful but I'd like to set the label depending on the value I get from the SQL query. See my edit to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the rowdatabound, and just need to convert your column into a template field.

Answer (score 0):

This is late reply, But it will help other people who come across same scenario.

[codezone4 tutorial](https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/asp-net-gridview-listview-column-data-binding/)